# usin polymer cdn polygit

Tags: polymer, rendering, cdn

I've been trying to use the polymer CDN ,  polygit on plunker but i can't even render a single polymer element. In the folowing plunk and code link i tried rendering a paper-tab and paper-button. Please can someone show me what i'm doing wrong. thanks.

https://plnkr.co/edit/z0y06qu4LdfpxhcpYyn7?p=preview

```
...
 <head>
    <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  ` <link  rel="import" href="paper-material/paper-material.html">
   <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
   <link href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body unresolved>
   <paper-button raised>New</paper-button>
   <paper-tabs>
      <paper-tab>Color</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>Code</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>Mark</paper-tab>
   </paper-tabs>
</body>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing protocol to `https` will solve you issue.

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
```

Comment: thanks. i just copied the link from polygit.org without checking that. i really appreciate your time and effort.